# Returning line number on match() Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function that detects a match in the textarea and then deletes the current block.

```
function deleteValue() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var textarea = document.getElementById("result");
  if (textarea.value.match("name"))
  {
    var lines = textarea.value.split('\n');
    lines.splice(3,8);
    var modify = lines.join('\n');
    textarea.value = modify;
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to add some logic to this to detect where `name` exist in the textarea and start from that line.  What javascript method should I implement?

Comment: Just go through the lines and test each one?

Comment: I'd rather have a more precise method. I thought about while-ing through, but I'd rather have a proper return.

Comment: Why do you think that would be unprecise? What do you understand by "proper"?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you mean by "more precise method" and "proper return".

Comment: It doesn't get more precise then what @Bergi offered. If you need a return value, wrap it in a function.

Comment: As in, I would like to be able to search the text using API methods instead of while and for loops. If possible, I would like the function to match the text in the area and return what line number it is found.

Comment: @Bergi So a while loop is the only way to determine where a value was found in an area?

Comment: @SethEarby: Yeah, yet you can use `indexOf`/`search` and then check in which line that index occured. But again you'll have to find about the positions of the linebreaks for that at first. There is no "API" for lines.

Comment: What about the positions of the linebreaks?  What does that entail?

Comment: It entails that you loop over them… (not necessarily with `while` of course)

Comment: Ok, quick question.  How could I determine when a match is found?  I have `while (textarea.value.match("name") != true)` is that correct?

Comment: @SethEarby: Definitely not. Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on what `match` returns.

Comment: I couldn't find much about matching strings or what it returns.  Is there away I can use a test or match method in a while loop?

Comment: I've linked "[the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)", you should be able to find it there. I don't get why you wanted to use that in a `while` loop condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the logic in a function that iterates through the lines of a given text and return a list with the indices of the lines matching a search pattern (or an exact search term).
Then, you can use those indices appropriatelly, e.g. removing those line from the original text.

```
function findMatches(text, pattern) {
    var matchingLines = [];
    var allLines = text.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++) {
        if (allLines[i].match(pattern)) {
            matchingLines.push(i);
        }
    }

    return matchingLines;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LC8xJ/)**.

Some points to keep in mind:
* In the above example, "pattern" is treated by JS as a regex pattern, e.g. "tes." would match "test", "tess", "tes6" etc. If you want a literal match instead, replace `allLines[i].match(pattern)` with `allLines[i].indexOf(pattern) != -1`.
* It is assumed that lines end with "\n". If your specifications are different, modify accordingly.
* In the short demo above, the line-finding part and the line-removing part are separated resulting in more complex code (for the sake of flexibility). If you only want to remove matching lines, you can achieve this in one pass, like this:

```
function removeMatches(text, pattern) {
    var outputLines = [];
    var inputLines = text.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputLines.length; i++) {
        if (!inputLines[i].match(pattern)) {
            outputLines.push(inputLines[i]);
        }
    }

    return outputLines.join("\n");
}
```